# How do I get value from associative array based on $_GET data

Tags: php

I have following array called $products:

```
Array
(
[SpringJacket] => Array
    (

        [8] => Array
            (
                [OID] => 8
                [Title] => Blossom Spring Jacket
                [Description] => Random Description
                [Option] => 8
                [Price] => $289.99
            )

[Coat] => Array
    (

        [M] => Array
            (
                [OID] => M
                [Title] => Cordon Crombie Coat
                [Description] => Description
                [Option] => M
                [Price] => $199.99
            )

    )
)
```

I want to assign variables such as $title, $price, $Description etc based on the $_GET["ID"]. ie; if the $_GET["ID"] is Coat, then I would like to assign the variables according to the right product's specification.

I have tried:

```
$title = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["Title"];
$price = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["Price"];
$ID = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["ID"];
$description = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["Description"];
```

but it says:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Title on line 18
```

And all the same for all the other one with its own line number.

PS: line 18 is

```
$title = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["Title"];
```

Comment: `$options` is not contained anywhere in the code you have shown us one single time, so that error message you quoted is completely without context here with the code you have shown.

Comment: are you fetching the array ?

Comment: Welcome. There's an `[M] => Array` "between" the Code and the Title. Have you tried `$title = $products[$_GET["ID"]]['M']["Title"];`?

Comment: Missing a semicolon before $options? But without enough code, we can't tell

Comment: I have assigned $options to the option part, for example [Option] => M, but it does not seem to work. others seem fine but still get no output

Comment: @dn Fer, thanks. I did forget the semicolon and that fixed the $option but now it flags me another error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo'
as I am trying to echo all the variables

Comment: Please update your question and include the code causing the error.

Comment: I think it should be accessed like this: `$title = $products[$_GET["ID"]]["M"]["Title"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About unexpected $options error:

As commented as an correct answer, you're missing a semicolon before $options.
When getting other errors after correcting, update your question, including the code which is causing the error or ask a new question.

About undefined index error:
Your indexes are incorrect. 
Your referencing to $products[an id][a title] while your array is like $products[an id][something else][a title]

Comment: I have updated the error message and added semicolon before $option, that is at the end of $description

Comment: Thanks for the hint on my array's structure:
" Your referencing to $products[an id][a title] while your array is like $products[an id][something else][a title] "